# pauseableBuffer with specific size?

Tags: javascript, c#, system.reactive, rxjs

How can I create a `pausableBuffered` observable where it only buffers the latest item?

Currently I've got an ugly workaround:

```
source.pauseableBuffered(pauser).debounce(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have two observable sequences
 1. The `source` sequence
 2. The `pauser` sequence `IObservable<bool>`

then you could just combine latest them

```
Observable.CombineLatest(
    source,
    pauser,
    (s,p)=>Tuple.Create(s,p))
.Where(t=>!t.Item2)
```

This now allows you to ignore values while `pauser` has pushed a 'true' value.

You then can simply stick replay(1) on the end of that.

```
Observable.CombineLatest(
    source,
    pauser,
    (s,p)=>Tuple.Create(s,p))
.Where(t=>!t.Item2)
.Replay(1)
//.Publish().RefCount(); //If required.
```

**EDIT**
The `Replay(1)` is just noise, and doesn't focus on the OP.

This code

```
var source = new Subject<int>();
var pauser = new Subject<bool>();

var query = Observable.CombineLatest(source, pauser, (s,p)=>Tuple.Create(s,p))
    .Where(t=>!t.Item2);

query.Dump();

pauser.OnNext(false);
source.OnNext(1);
source.OnNext(2);
source.OnNext(3);
pauser.OnNext(true);
source.OnNext(4);
source.OnNext(5);
source.OnNext(6);
pauser.OnNext(false);
source.OnNext(7);
source.OnNext(8);
```

Produces this result

```
1 
2 
3 
6 
7 
8
```

Comment: i don't think would fix the OPs issue. If `Replay` is after the `Where` then it will drop all values while paused and only emit the buffered value on resubscribe. OP wants the buffer to retain only the latest value that happens while paused and then emit that when it resumes

Comment: Updated post with code and result. OP can decide if this meets the requirements?

Comment: Maybe not, i am not sure if the "specific size' part of the OP is met here. However if the specific size is always 1,then success.